# Concatenating 2 sentence in the same element ImmutableJS

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6, immutability, immutable.js

Im trying concat 2 sentence that are the same Current Element and add a period to the end of each of immutable object

this is the input and my current code

```
const Immutable = require("immutable");
let error = Immutable.fromJS({
  name: ["This field is required", "Another error"],
  age: ["Only numeric characters are allowed"]
});

error.map((currElement, index) => {
console.log("The current iteration is: " + index);
console.log("The current element is: " + currElement);
});
```

my expect output is

```
 error = {
 name: "This field is required. Another error.",
 age: "Only numeric characters are allowed."
 };
```

Trail and error attempt

```
error.map((currElement, index) => {
  // console.log("The current iteration is: " + index);
  // console.log("The current element is: " + currElement);

  let element = currElement.get(0) + "." + " " + currElement.get(1) + ".";
  return console.log(element);
});
```

Its close but Im still not getting the right output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the methods on arrays can be found on immutable Lists, .join() is one of them so you should be able to do:

```
const newError = error.map((value) => {
  return value.map(v => `${v}.`).join(' ');
}).toJS(); // .toJS() if you want the object from your expected output
```

You should probably check that value is indeed a List before running .join() on it too.

Comment: Yes, thank you i complete forget about  trying to use template literally, what if i want the output to be immutable map would I simply replace .toJS() to  .immutable.map()?

Answer (score 0):

> what if i want the output to be immutable map - Mateen Kazia

Just remove .toJS() from the end. "map" function on immutable item will result in an immutable item